# Can you use a Honeywell HZ322 for zoning with a single-stage HVAC?

Tags: hvac, zoned-heating

The HVAC system in my home was already old when I bought the place a couple years ago, so I knew I would probably be replacing it before too long. The system is zoned with a Honeywell HZ322.  This was installed by a previous owner, and was in place when I bought the house.

Recently I had an issue where the compressor stopped working, and I thought, well, now's the time.  But then I had someone come out to take a look, and he said the compressor shut off because of some error code which he was able to clear and got the compressor running again.

However, in discussing the fact that the system was indeed old and probably on its last legs, he also told me that using a zoning system with a single-stage system was a no-no, and was adding stress to the system.  I have since seen the same rule mentioned a couple of places online.

So I'm doing some research to see if I can program the Honeywell to ignore the zones and just act as a fully single-stage system to reduce the stress on everything until we figure out what new system we want to get (including a proper two-stage or variable speed compressor).

However, in starting to figure out how to get the Honeywell to do what I want, I found [the manual online here](https://manuals.plus/honeywell/hz322-truezone-panel-manual), and it pretty clearly says right at the beginning:

> **APPLICATION**
>
> The HZ322 TrueZONE panel controls:
>
> - Heat pump systems with single-stage compressor and auxiliary heat;

So... that seems to indicate that they *intended* the HZ322 to be able to zone a system with a single-stage compressor?

What's going on here?

Can I safely leave my zoning "turned on" and not worry about stress to the system because Honeywell designed it that way, or is the broader "don't zone a single-stage system" rule still true, despite what the manual says? (And I should continue to figure out how to turn the zoning off for the time being?)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by having a zoned HVAC in the first place?

Comment: I live in DC, and as is typical of rowhomes here, the lowest level is an English basement that has been re-done as a 1 BR apartment, with full kitchen and bath. As a full living space independent from the rest of the house, it makes sense to have its own zone. (The rest of the house is the other zone.) But again - it wasn't me who tried to solve that problem, it was a previous owner. Seeing as how it makes sense for the house, though, I do plan on leaving the zoning system in place when I ultimately replace the aging HVAC.

Comment: I take it you live within DC proper then? (need to know so that I can pull the correct local Codes down, as this gets rather thorny due to the duct penetrating the floor-ceiling separating the two dwelling units, and the IRC and IBC impose different requirements on this -- normally, a duplex is an IRC building, but a duplex rowhome is not a "townhouse unit" under the IRC, so it'd fall under IBC jurisdiction instead)

Comment: Yep, within DC proper. Although it is fitted out to be a fully functional separate space, I don't think it's a "legal" separate rentable unit.  From my understanding (and I could be wrong), a legal separate rentable unit in DC has to have its own separate metered electricity, and not be accessible from the other unit in the interior.  The basement floor here does not have independent utilities, and there is an interior stairway connecting it to the upstairs. I was under the impression we could Air B&B it if we wanted to, but we're not even doing that, we use the space for ourselves.